# Adding Images to FlipView from Code

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro

I am trying to add some images to a `FlipView` using the following code:

```
for (int N = 1; N < 30; N++)
{
    string name = String.Format(@"ms-appx:/Gallery/{0:00}.jpg", N);
    Uri uri = new Uri(name);
    BitmapImage img = new BitmapImage(uri);
    MainFlipView.Items.Add(img);
}
```

but it only displays some texts. I defined the `FlipView` in my XAML:

```
    <FlipView x:Name="MainFlipView">
    </FlipView>
```

What should I do?

Comment: I suppose it's not enough just to fill your FlipView with data; you have to provide a template for it. Here's [a tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465425.aspx) for creating FlipView with WinJS, yet I feel it should be the same approach with C#/XAML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The text showing is a call to the ToString method of the BitmapImage because you have no DataTemplate defined. Define on:

```
<FlipView>
    <FlipView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Image Source="{Binding}" />
         </DataTemplate>
    </FlipView.ItemTemplate>
 </FlipView>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this format for entering the file name

> ```
> images\\Photos\\italia1.jpg
> ```

.here images and photos are obviously folders and italia1.jpg is the pic file. I have used this to set this image as the lock screen of the device. So maybe this is the format that could work for your flipview problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your path to the image should look like this:

```
string name = String.Format(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path + @"/Gallery/{0:00}.jpg", N);
```